# Remove/Hide (display:none) the graphical chart in small-mobile view - JS chart

Tags: chart.js

On a small mobile view,[see screenshot of mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RvVI.png) how do I hide (display:none) the graphical chart and keep only the labels visible?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cant, it also really goes against the part of using a charting lib, you are better off to make those labels in html and hide the whole canvas

Comment: @LeeLanalee, this does not go against using a charting lib. The chart and labels from the charting lib, display accurately on large and medium devices. Thus my question above... seems like the small view should be tweakable for the canvas.